# iOS Appdelegate Multiple 3rd party dependencies initialisation slows down app launch

Tags: ios, swift, performance, cocoapods, custom-controls

I have to use a lot of 3rd party dependencies (mostly analytics) in my project and every single one of them recommends to initialize its sdk in

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

*So I have something like this:*

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        
        //FB sdk
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        // Firebase
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // AppsFlyer
        AppsFlyerTracker.shared().appleAppID = AccessKeys.appleAppID

        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(AccessKeys.googleMapsApiKey)

        return true
    }
```

I think it slows down app's launch speed, furthermore it looks really ugly in my AppDelegate. How can I improve that? Is it a good idea to initialise some of these libraries in root (initial) view controller? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Instruments to more specifically find the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Trust me, there isn't much you can do if you have dependencies on all of these. On looking at the libraries you are using, there is only one thing I can suggest is, use [**Firebase crash reporting**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/) instead of Fabric. That would at least remove one dependency since  `FirebaseApp.configure()` would initialise Firebase crash reporting as well.

Comment: Absolutely, this provided AppDelegate is really tiny. He does not use any DI framework yet, that would be scary :D